# What is the meaning of $K/F$ is a cyclic extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, field-theory, galois-theory, definition

I have it that $K/F$ is a (finite) field extension, what is the definition
of when $K/F$ is called cyclic ?

I heard it while I studied Galois theory and it was defined as

> $K/F$ is called cyclic if $Gal(K/F)$ is a cyclic group

where the notation
$Gal$ means that $K/F$ is also Galois.

Does, in general, it means $Aut(K/F)$ is cyclic, without the requirement
that the extension is Galois ? (how it is defined in the literature/what
is the convention ?)

Comment: I've never seen the term used without the hypothesis that the extension is Galois. Calling $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)/\mathbb Q$ cyclic is strange! :P

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - I guess you are right. Do you want to make this an answer so I can accept ?

Comment: You can make the following definition. Let $ \mathbb{K} $ be a field and $ \mathbb{F} $ a subfield. We say that $ \mathbb{K}/\mathbb{F} $ is a **cyclic field extension** if and only if $ \mathbb{K}/\mathbb{F} $ is Galois and $ \text{Gal}(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{F}) $ is a cyclic group.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An extension of fields $K/L$ is called Galois if its both separable and normal. An extension is called abelian if $K/L$ is Galois and the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(K/L)$ is abelian and cyclic if the Galois group is cyclic.